# Code completion suggestions appearing multiple times in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, angular, webstorm

I am working on a project using Angular2 and I would like the IDE to provide me with code hints as I write my code.

I have enabled node_modules as a library and I can get code completion suggestions but the dropdown contains multiple times the same function names like the image below.

[image: Multiple entries for the same function]

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: If you are using Angular-CLI: File -> ProjectStructure -> Modules -> Exclude 'tmp'. (You can also exlude dist & node_modules)

Comment: I am not using Angular-CLI. Code completion options seem to be coming from node_modules (from protractor specifically) but I cannot exlude them as they are marked as library root